# Cannot start container: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using docker on my `CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)` with 16 GB RAM. My docker version is `Docker version 19.03.7`. Docker-compose version is `docker-compose version 1.23.2`. I have 30+ docker containers running on my machine.

Everything was working smoothly, but I ran into a problem. Sometimes, when I try to run a container I get this error

```
ERROR: for container_name  Cannot start service container_name: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: 
starting container process caused "process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"EOF\"": unknown
```

When I retry 3-5 times to run container, the container started successfully. Sometimes I need to restart docker service and my server to make it working. I don't know the exact reason why It is giving me this error sometimes and gets created successfully sometimes with same docker-compose file.

Can somebody explain this weird behavior of docker to me? Is it due to so many containers running on my machine or something else?

Comment: can you show dockerfile for container that has the above issue? what process running in the `CMD` or entrypoint?

Comment: Possibly you're running out of space for docker to create layers when it spins up a new container.

Comment: seems like this is an active issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40835

Comment: @Adiii issue is not related to CMD or ENTRYPOINT because the same container runs successfully in 3-5 attempts with same configurations and command.

Comment: I see so its random behaviour, and yeah I can see open issue commented by @MatusDubrava

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue:

> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:722: waiting for init preliminary setup caused: EOF: unknown

and the problem turned out to be the wrong version of my WSL distro, which was 1 instead of 2:

```
PS C:\Users\myself> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         1
```

So I used the `wsl --set-version` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install#upgrade-version-from-wsl-1-to-wsl-2) to upgrade it:

```
PS C:\Users\myself> wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
PS C:\Users\myself> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2
```

Then I was able to successfully build my Docker image.
Hope can help someone.

Comment: ended up doing this after couple of hours of time waste, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Came across [this link](https://medium.com/@npalmius/many-thanks-for-writing-this-up-i-eventually-got-everything-running-4d0783b7d96), which solved the issue for me. It apparently works for WSL, but definitely also for my Ubuntu 18.04 installation: the latest version(s) of docker have this problem, a few versions back they haven't.

Answer (score 0):

I am a complete newb to Docker and am running Linux 18.04.6 Bionic Beaver
docker --version reports Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~18.04.3

I'm not sure if this is the solution, but after reinstalling Docker from various unrelated problems I ran `runc init` and killed an old running dockerd process and was able to get hello-world to run. I've wasted so much time on it that I don't want to find the root cause.